# Flash drive USB Connector only goes halfway in

Tags: usb-flash-drive, hardware-failure, connector

This is a working flash drive with important files. Pulled it out after copying. Now does not go in. The two square slots on top of the connector looks filled in (no depth), as if the inside has moved forward (?) when flash drive was pulled out. Can try to push the Inside upper part of the connector (above the blue plastic) inwards with a thin screwdriver. Wondering if that will damage the drive or not. Would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

[image: Flash Drive Top]
[image: Flash Drive Connector]

Comment: can you post a photo of the connector ? might be able to judge it a little better rather than just the description.

Comment: Posted photos. Flash drive is intact (connector is the problem). If no easy solution, any way the plastic enclosure can be removed ? Thanks..

Comment: Sorry can't tell anything, nothing is understandable in the "Flash Drive Connector" photo...try posting it again with better focus on the connector so the inside is visible.
But if your question is that can you increase the space between the blue part and outer steel casing or the connector then yes you can increase that using a screwdriver but be very careful..you can keep a thin towel on the blue part and then use the screwdriver so as not to harm the contact points of the connector.

Comment: from the photos it doesn't look like the plastic enclosure needs to be removed...if possible post a better photo of the connector.